# Did the blade that stabbed Jorah snap?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In GoT S8 Ep3 when Jorah is stabbed defending Daenerys, does the dragonglass blade snap? Rewatched it a few times now and can't tell if the full blade is there when pulled out. If not, does that mean Jorah can come back as the new Night King?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the two stills below, from my watching of it the blade does not snap when pulled out, it looks like the full blade.

[image: Jorah is stabbed]

[image: The blade is pulled out]

However, this does not mean that Jorah will become a new Night King, even if the blade stayed in his chest. The process of creating a Night King by the Children of the Forest is more than just inserting the dragonglass, it involves magic. We see this with Benjen in that he had been stabbed in the heart with dragonglass yet was not a new Night King.

> **Benjen:** I led a ranging party deep into the North to find White Walkers. They found us. A White Walker stabbed me in the gut with a sword of ice. Left me there to die. To turn. The Children found me. Stopped the Walker’s magic from taking hold.
>
> **Bran:** How?
>
> **Benjen:** The same way they made the Walkers in the first place. You saw it yourself.
>
> **Bran:** Dragonglass. A shard of dragonglass plunged into your heart.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 6 Episode 6, "Blood of my Blood"</sub>

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if the blade snapped, but no, Jorah can not come back as the new Night King, or even a wight for that matter. It's not simply stabbing someone with dragonglass that created the Night King or creates White Walkers.

> And since the Night King was killed by Arya, Jorah can't be brought back as a wight either.

The Night King was created with the magic of the Children of the Forest.

Answer (score 2):

It didn't snap, as far as I can tell when rewatching the scene, but it is quite dark.

Doubtful he'll come back in any case since his body will likely be burned, along with all the dead, in the great pyre of the next episode.